LibraryImport causes Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() to always return 0
When converting
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool QueryServiceStatusEx(SafeHandle hService, int infoLevel, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint cbBufSize, out uint pcbBytesNeeded);

to the LoadLibrary equivivalent via latest VisualStudio 2022
[LibraryImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static partial bool QueryServiceStatusEx(SafeHandle hService, int infoLevel, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint cbBufSize, out uint pcbBytesNeeded);

retrieving the last error with Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() always returns 0.
Debugging revealed that the correct error code is available up to the end of the function call but gets lost
one step after it. This might be related to LibraryImport unsafe context
This is reproducible:
// 1st call to get the required size of the output buffer.
NativeMethods.QueryServiceStatusEx(ServiceHandle, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO /*0*/, zero, 0, out uint dwBytesNeeded);

int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

//For DllImport: err == 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER as expected)
//For LibraryImport: err == 0

Any suggestions?

Have you tried GetLastSystemError or GetLastPInvokeError?

@shingo Yes. Both return the same result. Upon last step of LibraryImport auto implementation it is 122, after that 0. Same as for GetLastWin32Error. BTW the result does not vary if GetLastError() gets directly called via pInvoke

I’ve retried LoadLibrary attribute for QueryServiceStatusEx but this time it works (independent of attached debugger).
Now all error codes (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error, Marshal.GetLastSystemError and Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError) show the same expected result 122 on first call.
I can only guess why it did not work the first time. These are the only actions I did since then:

Restart of Visual Studio (Maybe the automatically checked "Unsafe code" option did not make its way through)
Full rebuild of the project with preceding manual deletion of all bin and obj folders

